# How to delete line breaks?

Tags: line-breaking

So my text is following:

Input Latex:

```
texttext

ugly linebreak
```

Output:

```
texttext
  ugly linebreak
```

Desired Output:

```
texttext
ugly linebreak
```

how do I delete this space (at the points ...)? I know that when I write my latex code face-to-face, without adding any spaces, these linebreaks wont occur, but I would like not to do that. I tried the \nolinebreak fuction but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. What ugly line break? What does your actual code look like

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's quite difficult to interpret your question. TeX doesn't insert random line breaks, so there should be something in your code that causes it. Without seeing an example of code it's very hard to tell something more.

Comment: @daleif well it is hard to insert a linebreak here too, there is a blank space at the beginning of the word "ugly", just remove the dot and you will see that it doesnt start from the edge, but there is some white space added. how do I remove this space?

Comment: you can mark a code block by highlight and use `{}` in the editor here so we can see what your input looks like.  Tex only breaks a line short  of th text width if you instruct it to do so, so it is impossible to understand your question currently

Comment: if the text in your  question is your input file, you have `texttext` the end of a paragraph,  `.` then a word space, then `ugly linebreak`  so the output you get will be ugly and weird but exactly what you specified.

Comment: I edited my question, the problem is the white space at the beginning of the word ugly, how do I remove it

Comment: You do not get the output shown from the text you posted. You get an indent at the start of a paragraph but both of those lines start a paragraph.

Comment: paragraph indentation has been used to mark the start of a paragraph for hundreds of years "ugly" is not the usual word to describe it.  If you do not want indented paragraphs then (depending on your document class) you could try adding `\usepackage{parskip}`

Comment: `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` for a global effect, or `\noindent ugly linebreak`.

Comment: @Werner thats what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Also, if `ugly linebreak` isn't the start of a new paragraph, you should instead remove the blank line in your source code.  If you want to keep it there to visually set that part of your source code off, then you can instead have a single `%` on that line.

Answer (score 2):

The default layout uses indented paragraphs

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 

ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 
ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 
ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 
ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 


\end{document}
```

If you would rather have a layout using vertical space rather than indentation to mark paragraphs, then the `parskip` package may be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 
texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext 

ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 
ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 
ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 
ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak ugly linebreak 


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, the \noindent also helped me for local use

Comment: @user239654 if you find yourself using `\noindent` then something is wrong. The whole point of latex is to separate global style considerations from the actual text content. Choice of paragraph style should be a document-level choice. If you place `\noindent`  in individual paragraphs your document becomes that much less flexible or usable with different document classes.